# c++: - setting default initializer_list argument Y of size argument X, where X and Y are function parameters

Tags: c++, function, arguments, initializer-list

Consider the following code

```
enum class VAR_CHANGE{TYPE1, TYPE2, TYP3};
void cell ( const std::initializer_list<double>& values,
            const std::initializer_list<VAR_CHANGE>& change_type = [[[ !!!!!]]] )
{
    // do something
}
```

I want to replace the [[[ !!!!!]]] so that the default initializer list comes to

```
{VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1, VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1, ....}
```

of size

```
values.size()
```

I want to do this because usually, I want to pick enum type VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1 to all of the values in initializer list 'values'.
For example:

```
cell({1.2, 2.2, 6.7});
```

would actually be,

```
cell({1.2, 2.2, 6.7}, {VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1, VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1, VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1});
```

I can overload the function but wondering if there is a nice generic way to do it represented as one function instead of passing the size around to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack:

```
enum class VAR_CHANGE{TYPE1, TYPE2, TYP3};



void cell ( const std::initializer_list<double>& values,
            const std::initializer_list<VAR_CHANGE>& change_type = {} )
{
    if(values.size() > 0 && change_type.size()==0)
    {
        // default
    }
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    cell({12.4, 234.4});
    cell({12.4, 234.4}, {VAR_CHANGE::TYPE1, VAR_CHANGE::TYPE2});;
}
```

Or make it better!

Comment: Why do you need the weird global variable? Can't you just have a default of `= {}`? (I'm pretty sure you can, just tested it) http://ideone.com/7NEFvL